# Why not RIP-relative instruction with GCC -fPIC flag

Tags: c++, assembly, kernel, x86-64, osdev

I was trying to write a custom kernel for x86-64 bare bone on Apple Silicon MacBook using x86_64-elf-gcc compiler.

In one of my header file (Memory.hh), I declared a constant:

```
extern "C" const unsigned long kMemHighAddrDirectMappingBase;
```

In the source file (Memory.cc), I defined it:

```
extern "C" const unsigned long kMemHighAddrDirectMappingBase = 0xFFFF880000000000;
```

Then, I compiled using `x86_64-elf-gcc` with
`CFLAGS = -nostdlib -fPIC -fPIE -fno-builtin -nostdinc -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -g -c`, linked it with `LDFLAGS = -nostdlib --oformat elf64-x86-64`

I'm loading my kernel using a custom UEFI kernel loader, it does basic relocation for `ET_EXEC`-typed ELF64 kernel. In my case, it relocates the kernel to some random free address, such as `0x7EFE0000`. But when I try to print the address of the constant, it still prints out some address based on `0x400000` like `0x4072D0`.

I check the assembly by disassembling the kernel. The function calls and other global variables are addressed using RIP-relative mode, but for this constant, it's using absolute mode.

I'm wondering why it's not using RIP-relative mode for this constant, and how can I force it to use that. And if that is not possible, how can I resolve this.

I tried to change the declaration to

```
inline const unsigned long kMemHighAddrDirectMappingBase;
```

and removed the definition in the source file, and it works.

But I need it to be `extern "C"` and not inlined so that I can use the symbol in the assembly code.

The purpose of all these, is to relocate the kernel itself to some other location (including the kernel stack).

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: *But I need it to be extern "C" and not inlined so that I can use the symbol in the assembly code.* - It'd be better to also inline it in your asm, instead of making your C++ code-gen less efficient.  Using `-flto` for cross-file inlining may let it inline into other C++ code, while still instantiating it for access by asm if you can't just `%define` or `equ` it in your asm source (maybe with some build scripting to only actually define the constant once.)

Comment: If you link without `-pie` or `-shared`, you won't get a PIE executable unless your `gcc` has `-pie` enabled by default.  So yeah, addresses near the default base of `0x400000` are what you should expect, separate from whether the code uses RIP-relative addressing to reach variables or not.  (`-mcmodel=kernel` might be what you want for a non-PIE kernel loaded near the top of virtual address space.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The constant is expected to use across multiple asm and cpp files. How can I just define the value of the constant once, and use that constant in both asm and c++?

Comment: You define it in a `.asm` that you `%include` everywhere (if it's NASM), and in a `.h` that you include everywhere.  Or if you're using GNU assembler, you can `#define` it and use it in both C++ and asm.  If not, you could maybe with a little shell script or something to get the constant from a `.asm` and put it into a `.h` or vice versa, or from a config file or variable and create both a `.h` and an `include-constants.asm`.

Comment: @PeterCordes adding the `-flto` flag does the exact thing I need.

Comment: @PeterCordes I can now inline it in the cpp header file and use it by declaring extern symbol in the assembly file. Thanks